# Type hinting (annotation) error with global variable

Tags: python

This code works fine:

```
x: int = 10

def f(a):
    global x
    x = 1
    return x + a


print(x, f(7), x)
```

Producing `10 8 1`.

This code does not:

```
def f(a):
    global x
    x = 1
    return x + a


x: int = 10

print(x, f(7), x)
```

Producing a `SyntaxError: annotated name 'x' can't be global` on the type hinting line.

I fail to see the difference. Can you please explain why?

Comment: See https://bugs.python.org/issue34939